# Laravel sessions table user_id always null

Tags: php, laravel

I tried to set the session but the `user_id` column is always `null`. Other columns are working just fine. Is `user_id` reserved for anything? Did this happen to anyone? 
What I am trying here is to authenticate the user,save the data to session and redirect to dashboard.
Here is the code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $validator = validator::make($request->all(),[
        'username' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect('/')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validator);
    }
    $username = $request->get('username');
    $user = User::where('username', $username)->first();
    $checkpass = false;
    if(!empty($user)){
        $password = $request->get('password');
        $dbpass = $user->getAttributes()['pass'];
        $checkpass = Hash::check($password, $dbpass);
        if($checkpass){
            //saving session after success login check
            $request->session()->put('id',\Session::getId());
            $request->session()->put('user_id', $user->id);
            $request->session()->put('ip_address', $request->ip());
            $request->session()->put('user_agent', $request->header('User-Agent'));
            $request->session()->put('payload', base64_encode($request->getContent()));
            $request->session()->put('last_activity', time());
            //redirect to dashboard
            return redirect('/dashboard');
        }
    }
    if(empty($user) || $checkpass == false){
        $errors = new MessageBag(['password'=>['Email and/or password invalid.']]);
        return redirect('/')
        ->withErrors($errors)
        ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    }



}
```

Comment: Can u show the rest of the code starting with where u get the values

Comment: @tam only $request->session()->put('user_id', 11); is giving me null others are fine. Did it happened to anybody?

Comment: That is not what I asked, that was clear from your question. I asked for more information. Nonetheless, I have a hunch. Is the `user_id` still `null` when you make a request as an authenticated user?

Comment: I am not using Auth but a simple own login. Can't I do that?

Answer (score 8):

You are using the `database` session driver. Laravel will thus handle sessions via the `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler.php`. If you check out the source, you will find a method `getDefaultPayload` which is called whenever you `write/save` the session to the database.

Inside this method you will find this:

```
if ($container->bound(Guard::class)) {
    $payload['user_id'] = $container->make(Guard::class)->id();
}
```

which sets the `user_id` to the currently logged in user via Laravel's `Guard`. However, since you are not logging in with the `Guard`, this method will see the current user id as `null` and that is why you always get `null`.

Furthermore, in truth none of the properties you are setting are actually being set. Instead, they are all being set in the `getDefaultPayload` method of `DatabaseSessionHandler.php`.

This is where you should start in figuring out the best way to integrate Laravel's database session with your implementation. As I don't have more information about your application, I can't give you further direction as what the best solution might be and what would be the best change to make. Without knowing anything though, I might look into integrating your login system with the Laravel Guard because it does provide some other functionality as well. Or, a quicker solution might be to just directly modify this bit of the `getDefaultPayload` method.

Comment: I have updated the question with the full login method. What would be best for me then?

Comment: @BulletProof47 I have read through your code. It is not apparent to me why you would need to choose this login system over the default authentication that is provided by Laravel. My recommendation would be to refactor your code to use laravel's authentication system. You will still be able to do everything you are currently doing (from the code you showed) and it will turn out to be much simpler. If you need help with that let me know

Comment: So, I cannot update the session user_id ? If not then I will of course use default auth? Can you point me to any good tutorials. Thank you

Comment: If you really wanted to you could: you would have to work through the source code of the database session handler and change some of it, which will not be so straightforward and you will have to deal with serializing data. Another option could be to just create your own custom database session implementation as a regular table. HOWEVER, it seems like you are trying to fight the framework for no good reason, you are trying to do authentication on your own, and session handling on your own, while **both** of these things come out of the box and will achieve exactly what you want much simpler.

Comment: also i think you have to call the `save` method on the session if you want to persist it to the db

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am now going for laravel auth. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this under Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler.php

```
protected function performUpdate($sessionId, $payload)
{      
    if(!Auth::check())
    {
        unset($payload['user_id']);
    }        
    return $this->getQuery()->where('id', $sessionId)->update($payload);        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will fix if you using `Auth::attempt` because when you attempt the Auth facade laravel will set the user_id on the Session table/file/etc, something like this:

```
if(Auth::attempt([
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
])) {
        $user = Auth::user();

        return [
            'user' => $user,
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution by making some changes `Illuminate\Session\DatabaseSessionHandler.php`

```
/**
 * Add the user information to the session payload.
 *
 * @param  array  $payload
 * @return $this
 */
protected function addUserInformation(&$payload)
{
    if ($this->container->bound(Guard::class)) {
        $payload['user_id'] = $this->userId();
    }

    // UPDATE "user_id" IN TABLE "sessions" USING YOUR OWN SESSION DATA [BEGIN]
    if(\Session::has('login_id')){
        $my_user = \Session::get('login_id');
        $payload['user_id'] = $my_user;
    }
    // UPDATE "user_id" IN TABLE "sessions" USING YOUR OWN SESSION DATA [END]

    return $this;
}
```

But make sure the logged-in session has been created by your own auth function first.

Sample `dd(Session::all);` of my application:

```
array:8 [
  "_token" => "VSI617e5HjtrYnj59hGPG9AS0R7y5vvUA1fQ7mV6"
  "language" => "EN"
  "_previous" => array:1 []
  "_flash" => array:2 []
  "login_id" => "123"
]
```